# How to check the authenticity of a auth0 google JWT-token on the backend?

Tags: php, auth0

My Android/IOS application accesses Auth0 Google servers and, with the user’s permission, receives a JWT-token. The application passes it to my backend, where I parse it into header,payload,signature, and only check payload for the presence of the asp field, which should be equal to clientID.

```
$clientId = '....apps.googleusercontent.com';
// $idToken we receive from the application
    
$data = explode('.', $idToken);
list($header, $payload, $signature) = array_map('base64_decode', $data);

// this is the only authentication check
$jwt = json_decode($payload, true);
if ($jwt['azp'] !== $clientId) { die('Invalid client ID ');}

// checking token expiration date
$currentTime = time();
if ($jwt['exp'] < $currentTime) {  die('Token has expired'); } 

$client_info = $jwt;
```

I understand that the scheme is vulnerable, because if you know the clientID, you can slip a fake JWT-token with fake user data.

I think I should check header and signature, but I don't understand how. Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs: https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-php

In short, you need to do everything that you're doing AND then you're BE needs to ask auth0 "is the signature on this token valid" - i.e. can all the claims that I just verified actually be trusted?

Also, because I noticed it, under most circumstances you're not supposed to be passing ID tokens to your BE, you should be using access tokens.

Auth0 also has quickstarts/guides available on your dashboard, you should really take a look at those, they'll answer all your questions.

Comment: this is true, but this documentation refers to the use of SDK, and I would like to understand the signature verification myself...

Comment: Check the documentation for this package if you don't want to use the SDK: https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt. Your server needs to know how to acquire the public key of the system that issued the JWT (the public key is publicly available in the JWKS at the .well-known endpoint of your auth0 tenant). Once it acquires the public key, it uses it to verify that the JWT provided to your system for access was correctly signed. Please don't do this yourself, use a JWT package (like the one in this comment or the SDK in the answer). If you want to understand how it works, read the code.